# Devil-Shell code injected into my site

Tags: php, shell, security

I am looking for some advice - I hope someone can help

My php site got hacked and I just found this code 'Script Encoded by Devil-Shell':

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode($encoded)))
```

And all these random letters/numbers...

I have a few questions:

- What will happen if I delete this code? Will it have a knock on effect?
- Is my site ruined?
- Is there anything that can be done?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your site has been hacked.  You should delete that immediately, then fix the security hole that let it in.

Comment: The safest answer is to alert your hosting company, so they can investigate if any other clients (on the same server or not) are affected, and then restore *everything* you had from a known good backup. You do have backups, right?

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much looks like a backdoor - I'd suggest to comment this out.

As long as $encoded is a variable that can be set externally (through HTTP GET or POST for example), anyone can execute any code on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip it to see what it does. Ensure it cannot be executed. Understand the damage it has done

Find your flaw in security

Answer (score 0):

If that is PHP code, that is pretty serious, as they were able to append to a PHP file or to add their PHP malicious file. They basically own the server. Apart from general advices (fix your security, that can be a year of work :)) some real-life tips:

- Don't erase logs, application logs or web server or db logs; keep them, it is very unlikely someone injected anything bad (apart from strings) there. Collect and keep all the logs, trust me they will be useful in the future if something bad happens.
- They could have compromised the whole server with an attack like that. You need to be careful with your hosting company: they could consider you responsible for data breaches in other people's data, config, etc... It depends on their configuration and the agreement you signed with them.
- Do not consider anything safe: the DB could be compromised as well, all keys and passwords and passphrases and sessionIDs you have stored since now are insecure and are in the hands of them now. So replace them ALL, as their aim could be not you but your user, and they are totally in control of their browsers too now (if they want).
- You can comment that out, it seems safe enough; but they will add it again, in more subtle forms. Consider that.
- Check (if you can) the traffic FROM your website. Usually they build simple webshells like that to be part of a bigger botnet. Usually they are used for Distribuited Denial of Service (DDOS), bitcoin mining or traffic exchange. So you could be considered legally responsible for such attacks/illegal behaviours as they are connected to your account and it is yours the contract for hosting.

In the internet this topic is called 'Intrustion Response' or 'Attack Response'. It is usually tailored only for big enterprises so I doubt you can find anything useful, but at least for theoretical topics it may help to google for it http://www.certiguide.com/secplus/cg_sp_SixStepIncidentResponseProcess.htm